# Matlab's cconv() for Octave

Tags: octave

Apparently the [cconv](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/ref/cconv.html) function is not yet implemented for [Octave's signal package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/). What is a simple way to reproduce its functionality?

The code which would like to execute is:

```
pkg load signal
n=linspace(0,1,1024);
s=sin(2.*pi.*1.*n)+.3.*sin(2.*pi.*4.*n);                  
x=s+.1.*randn(size(s));
L=100;         
y=cconv(x,ones(1,L)./L,1024);
figure,plot(y);
xlabel('n'),ylabel('y[n]'),title('Output y[n]')
```

But the following error message is shown after trying to use cconv():

```
warning: the 'cconv' function belongs to the signal package from Octave Forge but
has not yet been implemented.
```

The code is an assignment provided by [edX' "Discrete Time Signals and Systems"](https://www.edx.org/course/ricex/ricex-elec301x-discrete-time-signals-1032) where an integrated Matlab-interface is provided. I would like to use Octave though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function a = cconv( b, c )

  nb = length(b) ;
  nc = length(c) ;

  ##
  ## Ensure the two vectors are the same length
  ##
  if (nb < nc)
    b = [ b zeros(1,nc-nb) ] ;
  endif

  if (nc < nb)
    c = [ c zeros(1,nb-nc) ] ;
  endif

  a = ifft(fft(b) .* fft(c)) ;

  ##
  ## Get rid of any tiny imaginary bits that should be zero
  ##
  if (all(b == real(b)) && all(c == real(c)))
    a = real(a) ;
  endif

endfunction
```

([source](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Circular-convolution-td1611981.html))

Answer (score 1):

What about this implimentation from File Exchange?

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13030-circular-convolution/content/cconv.m

Comment: looks promising! it's not working plug and play though, as it expects both vectors to be of same length. But I guess this can be amended easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do circular convolution that gives identical results to the ifft(fft.*fft) method.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,3,2,5,0,1,-10,-1,3];

h=[0.5, 0.3, 0.15, 0.05];

Lx=length(x);

Lh=length(h);

y=zeros(1,Lx+Lh-1);

% circular convolution without zero padding and fft

y=conv([x((end-Lh+2):end) x],h);

y1=y(Lh:end-Lh+1)

% fft method for circular convolution (must zero pad to equal size)

y2=ifft(fft(x).*fft([h zeros(1,Lx-Lh)]))
```